# Doubts in Source IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So I have two instances in GCP both with static external IP addresses. Also in the firewall rules, I have enabled communication between the two instances using their external IP's.
Now I have a machine A with external IP **a.b.c.d** and I am sending UDP packets to machine B with external IP **e.f.g.h**. Now when I capture the UDP packets in machine B using tcpdump the IP shown there is something like **x.y.z.w.bc.googleusercontent.com**. Shouldn't tcpdump show the source IP as **a.b.c.d**.
Please Help.

Comment: do you use load balancers?

Comment: Is **x.y.z.w** equal to **d.c.b.a** or is it a completely different address?

Comment: I have not used load balancers and x.y.z.w is completely different to a.b.c.d

Comment: The packets caught by `tcpdump` should be identified with the PTR record of the source host that contains the source IP in  reverse notation: `d.c.b.a.bc.googleusercontent.com`. Since the caught IP is completely different, you could catch network packets that don't belong to the source host A. Can you ping the machine B from A? If so, what is the output of `tcpdump` in this case? To filter by source IP, you can use syntax `tcpdump src a.b.c.d`.